# Colleagues going overboard as they get more envious

Tags: management, work-environment, colleagues

One of my cousins has joined an year old startup. She is full of ideas and expressed it right at the time of interview. The panel was impressed with her.

With a period of 2-3 months, she introduced a lot of new things into the company and the management appreciated it. Only they did it in front of other staff and not directly to her; their exact words were 'She is doing a terrific job', 'Look at the way she is working.' and so on. She, obviously, incurred a lot of enemies in a very short span of time.

As a result, she would meet colleagues who look at her angrily, even from someone whom she never met or doesn't even know that they exist, or she would come across people who literally stand in front of her and stare angrily at her while she is working, or mock her by saying something like, 'the boss is saying that your work is very good' etc etc. You get the point.

My cousin was oblivious of all these things and was thoroughly doing her job. It is important to note that never did the management appreciate her work directly but gave her all the resources that she needed.

And then an incident occurred. A colleague asked her to do a task A but since my cousin was busy she gave a proper reason and couldn't take up that task. Within five minutes, the management called her and rebuked her very badly for not taking up that task A. She was not given a chance to explain either.

At the same time, she is not one of those who cries like other women do. She was very upset about it and her face reflected that. But, never cried. She understood that the colleague who requested her to do that task A never mentioned the reason for not doing the job but merely complained about her to the management.

She narrated all these incidents to me a few days back. She still has many ideas that she can implement but now that she has created many enemies within the organization, she is not really sure how she has to handle it. At the same time, the management didn't appreciate her directly and in fact they instigated her other colleagues into getting jealous and indirectly created enemies for her. Now, that when a complaint was lodged against her, management didn't bother to look at both sides of the coin.

She wants to continue to work in the organization for some more time. But, she wants to know if she really needs to put her ideas into implementation at this stage or should she lay low and do only the tasks assigned to her? What do you suggest her to do?

Comment: I notice a lot of your questions involve making management upset while being a top worker that everyone praises. How can one be both of those? Perhaps it is time to quit this job and move elsewhere instead of being in such a contradicting work environment?

Comment: @Dan My cousin has 2 years of experience and she feels that she can learn a lot from this startup and hence not willing to leave the company this soon. I guess her decision making skills needs to be honed now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> What do you suggest her to do?

If she is in the middle of another task, and get's asked to do something else, I would suggest she let's **her manager** decide.  This way she cannot be put in that position again.

In regards to jealous colleagues, there isn't *much* she can do about that.  One thing she *could* try is asking other members of her team to work with her on tasks.   This way it is a **team effort** versus a one person show.

I would be more concerned about my *first* point over the second one.

Comment: A simple, *"Boss, person A wants me to do Task A, but I'm in the middle of X. What do you want me to work on?"* Boss would most likely say, *"Task A takes priority, do that now."*